# Is the ocean at either end of the map infinite?

Tags: terraria

I am wondering if the oceans at either end of the map are infinite. I want to use one as my primary source of water by using 2 pumps and an insanely long wire (using a sky bridge) to pump water back to my base, while at the same time using it for my Obsidian Farm. I'd rather not have to worry about setting up a second water source in the middle of Hardcore Mode.

Comment: Note that wire connections can only be 2,000 blocks long, otherwise they won't work.

Comment: Also, a skybridge can interfere with your meteors!

Comment: PROTIP: StackExchange works best if you ask for solutions to problems, not if a solutions you thought of would work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not infinite, see the wiki:

> - Players may attempt to drain the ocean by tunneling down to the
>     Underworld, where water evaporates. The **Ocean is in fact drainable
>     this way**, and this method will allow the player to go back to the
>     Ocean floor and easily pick up all the Coral without worry of
>     suffocating. However, no Sharks will spawn once the Ocean is drained,
>     and previously-spawned Sharks will have vanished. Therefore, draining
>     will not allow a player to obtain Shark Fins and the Diving Helmet.
> - Another way of **draining the ocean** is by making an air pocket, empty a
>     bucket of lava in it and place an object that can't be destroyed by
>     lava in the lava. After that allow the water to flow into the lava.
>     The object will prevent obsidian from being generated, causing all the
>     water to disappear.

Comment: but can you fill up the ocean again afterwards?

Comment: You can, but as the wiki says, Sharks will not spawn oncec the Ocean is drained

Answer (score 4):

1. If your house is over 2000 blocks (4000 feet) you would need multiple wire networks to move the water, as a single wire 'network' can only consist of 2000 wire.
2. Just use an [infinite water source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Making_liquid#Infinite_fluid) if you need alot of water.

Answer (score -1):

I think people are misinterpreting the question. There are only certain ways to drain the ocean. You can keep pumping from it indefinitely.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back this up?

Answer (score -2):

Pumps don't work at all because I'm currently draining the ocean using pumps and the ocean is not going down at all. So dig to hell to drain it but think before you do. Get all the shark fins you need before draining it.

Comment: There are TWO oceans, so you can drain one without thought if wanted.